# MERGE statement in stored procedure throwing duplicate rows error

Tags: c#, sql-server, merge

I'm using a C# console application to insert some data into a SQL Server table and I'm running into an issue:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.'

I've got a method in the C# code to remove any dups and I've also check for duplicate rows in Excel with a formula, I don't see any in my source data. This method returns the same number of records I feed it.

```
public static DataTable RemoveDuplicatesRecords(DataTable dataTable)
{
    var uniqueRows = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Distinct(DataRowComparer.Default);
    var dataTableOutput = uniqueRows.CopyToDataTable();

    return dataTableOutput;
}
```

This is the stored procedure:

```
BEGIN

MERGE INTO Imp_Master_DSDCostPrice AS Target
USING @UpdateRecords AS Source ON Target.ItemUPC = Source.ItemUPC 
                               AND Target.Store = Source.Store 
                               AND Target.RoutingEffectiveDate = Source.RoutingEffectiveDate

WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET 
        Target.APVendor = Source.[APVendor],                                
        Target.POVendor = Source.[POVendor],
        Target.[ArticleNo] = Source.[ArticleNo],
        Target.[CostGroup] = Source.[CostGroup],
        Target.Store = Source.[Store],
        Target.[CostPrice] = Source.[CostPrice],
        Target.[ItemPack] = Source.[ItemPack],
        Target.[CostEffectiveDate] = Source.[CostEffectiveDate],
        Target.[CostEndDate] = Source.[CostEndDate],
        Target.[RetailPrice] = Source.[RetailPrice],
        Target.[RetailEffectiveDate] = Source.[RetailEffectiveDate],
        Target.[RetailEndDate] = Source.[RetailEndDate],
        Target.[DSDTableNo] = Source.[DSDTableNo],
        Target.[OrgGroupNo] = Source.[OrgGroupNo]
       
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN           
    INSERT (APVendor,
        POVendor,
        ItemUPC,            
        ArticleNo,
        CostGroup,
        Store,
        RoutingEffectiveDate,
        RoutingEndDate,
        CostPrice,
        ItemPack,
        CostEffectiveDate,
        CostEndDate,
        RetailPrice,
        RetailEffectiveDate,
        RetailEndDate,
        DSDTableNo,
        OrgGroupNo
        )
    VALUES (Source.APVendor,
        Source.POVendor,
        Source.ItemUPC,
        Source.ArticleNo,
        Source.CostGroup,
        Source.Store,
        Source.RoutingEffectiveDate,
        Source.RoutingEndDate,
        Source.CostPrice,
        Source.ItemPack,
        Source.CostEffectiveDate,
        Source.CostEndDate,
        Source.RetailPrice,
        Source.RetailEffectiveDate,
        Source.RetailEndDate,
        Source.DSDTableNo,
        Source.OrgGroupNo
        );
END
```

The columns of `ItemUPC`, `Store`, and `RoutingEffectiveDate` make up the primary key in the table.

Is there a better way to approach the SQL side here?

Comment: You should properly test your table mp_Master_DSDCostPrice and source @UpdateRecords using row_number() over() to see if there is any duplicate.may be Source having duplicate

Comment: Aside... not the cause of your problem, but the update portion of the merge statement is setting `Target.Store = Source.[Store]` instead of `RoutingEffectiveDate`.

Comment: Seems like `RemoveDuplicatesRecords` is producing entirely distinct rows, but does that mean that every row actually has distinct combinations of `ItemUPC, Store, RoutingEffectiveDate`?

Comment: make sure the columns data type  in the DataTable is matching the columns in the database.  The types if not the same may cause issues.  Also read following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks

Comment: `Target.Store = Source.[Store],` makes no sense, it is already the same in the `WHEN MATCHED`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing complete duplicate rows from the DataTable is not enough.  You must ensure there is only one row in the DataTable for the match condition.

```
 ON Target.ItemUPC = Source.ItemUPC 
AND Target.Store = Source.Store 
AND Target.RoutingEffectiveDate = Source.RoutingEffectiveDate
```

You can do this in SQL Server by merging from a CTE that dedups the input, something like:

```
with q as 
(
  select *, row_number() over (partition by ItemUPC, Store order by RoutingEffectiveDate desc) rn
  from @UpdateRecords
), q2 as
(
  select * from q where rn = 1
)
MERGE INTO Imp_Master_DSDCostPrice AS Target
USING q2 AS Source . . .
```